# How to attach CloudWatch rule to SNS topic correctly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to start StepFunction from CloudWatch. This works like a charm when event source is a schedule. However, when I try to create event pattern to watch corresponding SNS topic, CloudWatch doesn't sees publications to it.
I've tried both default pattern:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.sns"
  ]
}
```

And using arn:

```
{
  "resources": [
    "// SNS topic arn here"
   ],
}
```

In both cases when I publish to the topic nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?
Update: unfortunatelly I can't understand what is "Event Pattern" rule for, it doesn't work in other condition - even when event is pushed manually from lambda. The approach to my problem I currently see is to create CloudWatch schedule rule to start every 1-3 seconds, disable it. Then from a lambda I was going to push event to SNS enable this CloudWatch rule to fire. When it fires and start Step Function, inside Step Function disable the rule. It's nonsense but it should work.

Comment: Did you go through : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_SetupSNS.html

Comment: @KushVyas It's about email subscription to SNS FROM SNS interface. There is no CloudWatch option in SNS interface, so CloudWatch subscription can be done only FROM CloudWatch interface. And currently I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?  I am trying to do something similar.

Comment: @JCalbreath Unfortunately not. The final solution was some workaround using other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your SNS topic has a policy set that allows events.amazonaws.com to publish to it, such as:

```
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["SNS:Publish"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["events.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    resources = ["${aws_sns_topic.sns_topic.arn}"]
  }
```

Comment: This is the answer. A more clear example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59032142/terraform-cloudwatch-event-that-notifies-sns?rq=1