# Terraform: CloudWatch Event that notifies SNS

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I'm learning TF and trying to apply an infrastructure that creates:

1. a simple lambda function
2. an SNS topic
3. get that lambda to subscribe the SNS topic
4. a Cloud Watch Event that publishes a message to the topic at some interval
5. a Cloud Watch Log Group to check if the lambda gets notified by the SNS
6. The lambda permission to allow calls from SNS

I'm able to apply that successfully. The infrastructure seems perfectly fine (it has the same aspect when I create that myself through the visual aws console)

But the cloud watch Event doesn't get triggered (when built from TF), so no message is published to SNS and lambda doesn't get called. I don't know why

Anyone know how can I accomplish that? Bellow my .tf script:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

//lambda function handler & code file
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda-function" {
  function_name = "Function01"
  handler = "com.rafael.lambda.Function01"
  role = "arn:aws:iam::12345:role/LambdaRoleTest"
  runtime = "java8"
  s3_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.sns-test.id
  s3_key = aws_s3_bucket_object.file_upload.id
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("../target/sns-cw-lambda-poc.jar")
}

//allow sns to call lambda
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow-sns-to-lambda" {
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda-function.function_name
  action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  principal = "sns.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn = aws_sns_topic.call-lambdas-topic.arn
  statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromSNS"
}

//app s3 repository
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "sns-test" {
  bucket = "app-bucket-12345"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

//app jar file
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "file_upload" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket.sns-test
  ]
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.sns-test.id
  key = "sns-cw-lambda-poc.jar"
  source = "../target/sns-cw-lambda-poc.jar"
  server_side_encryption = "AES256"
  etag = filebase64sha256("../target/sns-cw-lambda-poc.jar")
}

//to check lambda exec logs
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "lambda-cloudwatch-logs" {
  name = "/aws/lambda/${aws_lambda_function.lambda-function.function_name}"
  retention_in_days = 1
}

//rule to trigger SNS
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "publish-sns-rule" {
  name = "publish-sns-rule"
  schedule_expression = "rate(1 minute)"
}

//cloud watch event targets SNS
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "sns-publish" {
  count = "1"
  rule = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.publish-sns-rule.name
  target_id = aws_sns_topic.call-lambdas-topic.name
  arn = aws_sns_topic.call-lambdas-topic.arn
}

//SNS topic to subscribe
resource "aws_sns_topic" "call-lambdas-topic" {
  name = "call-lambdas-topic"
}

//lambda subscribes the topic, so it should be nofied when other resource publishes to the topic
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "sns-lambda-subscritption" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.call-lambdas-topic.arn
  protocol = "lambda"
  endpoint = aws_lambda_function.lambda-function.arn
}
```

Comment: Is the cloudwatch event getting triggered when you create the resources using AWS console?

Comment: yes, CloudWatch event gets triggered when I build that same infrastructure using AWS console. Lambda is notified by SNS at the specified interval. I can assure this by checking the cloud watch log group.

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out, I forgot to add the SNS policies that allow CloudWatch to publish to SNS topic. To get the above script to work, just add this:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "default" {
  count  = 1
  arn    = aws_sns_topic.call-lambdas-topic.arn
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns_topic_policy.0.json}"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns_topic_policy" {
  count = "1"
  statement {
    sid       = "Allow CloudwatchEvents"
    actions   = ["sns:Publish"]
    resources = [aws_sns_topic.call-lambdas-topic.arn]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["events.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```