# AWS S3 events handling with SNS using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

Trying to setup AWS S3 Event Rule but events aren't being caught. Possibly I'm missing something in thr **event-pattern** or sns aim policy. To test It I'm creating email subscription using aws console because terraform doesn't support sns email subscription at this moment of time. Did anybody have the same issues?

Event rule declaration:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "this" {
  name        = "some-rule"
  is_enabled  = true
  description = "some-rule"

  event_pattern = <<PATTERN
{
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
   "Events S3"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CopyObject",
      "CompleteMultipartUpload",
      "PutObject"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
          "${local.bucket_name}"
      ]
    }
  }
}
PATTERN
}
```

SNS topic declaration:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "this" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.this.name
  target_id = null
  arn       = aws_sns_topic.topic.arn
}



resource "aws_sns_topic" "topic" {
  name = "some-topic"
  kms_master_key_id = data.aws_kms_key.common_key.key_id
  policy = <<POLICY
  {
      "Version":"2012-10-17",
      "Statement":[{
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {"Service":"s3.amazonaws.com"},
          "Action": "SNS:Publish",
          "Resource":  "arn:aws:sns:${var.aws_region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:some-topic",
          "Condition":{
              "ArnLike":{"aws:SourceArn":"${aws_s3_bucket.artifact-store.arn}"}
          }
      }]
  }
  POLICY
}
```

What is interesting that alternative approach is working:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "s3_notif" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.artifact-store.id}"
  topic {
    topic_arn = "${aws_sns_topic.topic.arn}"
    events = [
      "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RCA: I forgot to add CloudWatch permissions to be able to publish sns messages:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "default" {
  count  = 1
  arn    = aws_sns_topic.topic.arn
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns_topic_policy_cw.0.json}"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "default2" {
  count  = 1
  arn    = aws_sns_topic.topic.arn
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns_topic_policy_s3.0.json}"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns_topic_policy_cw" {
  count = "1"
  statement {
    sid       = "Allow CloudwatchEvents"
    actions   = ["sns:Publish"]
    resources = [aws_sns_topic.topic.arn]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["events.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

[Terraform: CloudWatch Event that notifies SNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59032142/terraform-cloudwatch-event-that-notifies-sns?rq=1)